# How to cast element from adapter when using multipleview and Picasso

Tags: java, android

How to cast a `CircleImageView` element inside the adapter when using `MultipleView` and `Picasso` ?

I created a `MultipleView` inside my adapter to distinguish `Views` displayed. When I display `TextView` only, everything runs perfectly without error. But when using `CircleImageView` I get an error on an application like this :

```
Process: com.bertho.chat, PID: 2731
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.bertho.chat.Adapter.AdapterMessage$RightBubbleMessage cannot be cast to com.bertho.chat.Adapter.AdapterMessage$LeftBubbleMessage
at com.bertho.chat.Adapter.AdapterMessage.onBindViewHolder(AdapterMessage.java:113)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6477)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6510)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5453)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5719)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5558)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5554)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1556)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:618)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3694)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3411)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3963)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1080)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2685)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16722)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2175)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1935)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1111)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6017)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$M
```

My **Adapter :**

```
public class AdapterMessage extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Messages> mMessageList;

    public class LeftBubbleMessage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageText;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;

        public LeftBubbleMessage(View view) {
            super( view );
            messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_text_layout );
            profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_profile_layout );
        }
    }

    public class RightBubbleMessage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView messageText;
        public CircleImageView profileImage;

        public RightBubbleMessage(View view) {
            super( view );
            messageText = (TextView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_text_layout );
            profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_profile_layout );
        }
    }

    public AdapterMessage(Context mContext, List<Messages> mMessageList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mMessageList = mMessageList;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView;

        if (viewType == 1) {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
                    .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_left, parent, false );
            return new LeftBubbleMessage( itemView );
        } else {
            itemView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
                    .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_right, parent, false );
            return new RightBubbleMessage( itemView );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Messages msg = mMessageList.get( position );

        if (holder.getItemViewType() == 1) {
            ((LeftBubbleMessage) holder).messageText.setText( msg.getMessage() );
            Log.i( "ON_BIND", msg.getProfile_pic().toString() );

            Picasso.with( mContext )
                    .load( msg.getProfile_pic() )
                    .placeholder( R.drawable.no_profile )
                    .into( ((LeftBubbleMessage) holder).profileImage );
        } else {
            ((RightBubbleMessage) holder).messageText.setText( msg.getMessage() );
            Log.i( "ON_BIND", msg.getProfile_pic().toString() );

            Picasso.with( mContext )
                    .load( msg.getProfile_pic() )
                    .placeholder( R.drawable.no_profile )
                    .into( ((LeftBubbleMessage) holder).profileImage );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mMessageList.get( position ).getTypeMsg();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mMessageList.size();
    }
}
```

All code goes well and the look is what I want. It's just that I can't `cast` `profileImage` to `CircleImageView` so my URL Path from the server does not show up on `CircleImageView` in my layout.

Is there something wrong in my code? Because I have made code like this :

```
profileImage = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById( R.id.message_profile_layout );
```

Thanks for advice

Comment: Why you are casting  *LeftBubbleMessage*; in else part also?
That is the real issue

Comment: @RamPrakashBhat Oh my god....My mistake... :(

Answer (score 1):

the OOD solution would be to create an `abstract class BubbleMessage extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder` and extend it in both Left and Right classes and move the fields up.

but you can simply do it with using the same ViewHolder class for two different layouts as long as fields have the same IDs and same logic (as I can see from your code they do)

this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;

    if (viewType == 1) {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
            .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_left, parent, false );
    return new LeftBubbleMessage( itemView );
} else {
    itemView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
            .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_right, parent, false );
    return new RightBubbleMessage( itemView );
}
```

}

would become this:

```
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView;

    if (viewType == 1) {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
                .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_left, parent, false );
    } else {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from( parent.getContext() )
                .inflate( R.layout.message_single_layout_right, parent, false );
    }

    return new BubbleMessage( itemView );
```

}

Comment: Thanks @Nick for your solution... I'll try

Answer (score 0):

My mistake... Thanks @Ram Prakash Bhat

I dont see this line :

```
.into( ((LeftBubbleMessage) holder).profileImage );
```

In the `else` part should be `RightBubbleMessage` not `LeftBubbleMessage`